# Add Custom Post Type as top level menu item for a custom page

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I am writing a plugin and I have added a custom post type

`register_post_type( 'my_cpt', $args);`

I would like to have it linked to the custom admin menu I have created using

`add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Item', 'manage_options', 'myplugin_page', 'mycallback', 'some_icon', 10);`

I basically want the top-level Admin Menu above to show the view that has all the posts for this CPT and has the option to add new below. I was able to get it somewhat working using

`add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Item', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=my_cpt', 'mycallback', 'some_icon', 10);`

This allowed the CPT to be on the Top level menu but only adding new posts had the correct view. The list of CPTs was not on the main menu item page.

Also, all the subpages were gone, since the slug for the top level menu item was gone.

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do? The top level admin page should be `edit.php?post_type=my_cpt`, below it I want the first submenu to point to `post-new.php?post_type=my_cpt` then the other submenus I can do what I want with them.

I have seen others add CPT to submenus. How do I add to the top level menu?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the admin menu yourself, when registering your post type just make sure you set the `public` argument to `true`. If the post type isn't public, then make sure at least `show_ui` is true. Then the menus will be created for you.

```
register_post_type( 'my_cpt', array(
    'public'  => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
) );
```

Refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for the arguments that determine where in the menu it appears and what icon is used.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I want the admin menus for the CPT to be used in custom admin menus I am creating. I was wondering if I should add my sub menus to the CPT admin menu. Is that how I am supposed to accomplish what I want....